# Two items with same id, but always only showing one

Tags: html

I want to know, if is a bad practice have 2 o more html items like `<div>` with the same "ID", but always only showing one, the items never will have conflicts.

Thanks.

Comment: Should be ok if you ***render*** only one of them (if you're using any kind of server-side code). There should not be two elements with the same id on the same page.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Yes, it is. Why would you do that anyway?

Comment: Id's have to be unique, use classes instead.

Comment: -1 too unclear - please provide an example!

Comment: Excuse me Philipp, I thought it was not necessary with a simple question....

Comment: An example isn't strictly necessary here, however this question shows no research effort. A simple Google search give you the answer many times over. Ex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.id "The ID must be unique in a document".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is bad practice. ID's should [**always be unique**](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm). 
Use a [**class**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/class) instead if you want to target multiple elements.

There isn't really any justifiable case you could provide where using duplicate ID's over a class would suffice (there's no disadvantage you'll face from using classes instead of ID's, only the added bonus of being able to use them on however many elements you want). You should try to use ID's as sparingly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

ID's are unique, there should be one per page always. A *class* however can be used multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You cant show two divs with the same ID. first one gets showed. If you want of the same styling, you could use Class or:

`#div1 , #div2{
  /*stylehere*/
}`